# Numbering equations and placing notes in appendix with enotez

Tags: table-of-contents, equations, numbering, footnotes, endnotes

I have footnotes and endnotes that I want in a chapter in the appendix. These foot/endnotes are also hyperlinked. I use `enotez` for this purpose but I notice there are some issues.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{enotez} 
\let\footnote\endnote
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}

my first equation:
\begin{equation}
a-b-c
\end{equation}

\section{section}
first\footnote{hello}, 

second\endnote{this is my equation
\begin{equation}
z=x+y
\end{equation}
}

third\endnote{another equation $a+b+c$}

\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notes}

%\chapter{these are my notes}
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Any equations in these foot/endnotes aren't formatted as `A.1`, `A.2`, etc. which is what I want. Equation numbers seem to follow the values in the previous chapter.

Also, the appendix title doesn't appear at all unless I define some appendix chapter `\chapter{these are my notes}`. Even then, the start of the foot/endnotes are pushed to another page. I want to print an appendix title for the appendix and for `Appendix` to appear in the table of contents.

What is the easiest way to fix these issues?

Comment: `\appendix` does not output anything itself, it sets some macros etc., but even with `appendix` package, there is no direct typesetting from `\appendix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\appendix` does not much apart from redefining `\chaptername` and `\thechapter`.

However, `\theequation`, the equation counter formatter, performs some check whether `c@chapter` is greater than 0 and uses `\thechapter`, otherwise it will just output only the equation number with out any prefix or suffix.

Solution: Use a `\chapter` command or increase the chapter number manually ( or redefine `\theequation` for the `appendices` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{enotez} 
\let\footnote\endnote
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}

my first equation:
\begin{equation}
a-b-c
\end{equation}

\section{section}
first\footnote{hello}, 

second\endnote{this is my equation
\begin{equation}
z=x+y
\end{equation}
}

third\endnote{another equation $a+b+c$}

\begin{appendices}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notes}
\stepcounter{chapter}%
\printendnotes

\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer it looks nice. Is there a way to put `Appendix` on the same page as `Notes` so that it has the same format as chapter 1?

Comment: Not without manipulating the `\appendixpage` command